# MaterializeCss carousel not working on mobile

Tags: angular, angular2-template, materialize

I am using angular2-materialize in my project.

My carousel works fine on desktop, but in mobile it **doesn't swipe**.

I already tried all the examples from the docs and I get the same results: works on desktop, but not on mobile.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  /* Materialize CSS Plugins */
  ngOnInit() {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      //Initialize collapse button
      jQuery(".button-collapse").sideNav();
      // Initialize collapsible (uncomment the line below if you use the dropdown variation)
      jQuery('.collapsible').collapsible();

      //Initialize carousel
           jQuery('.carousel').carousel({
            dist:0,
            shift:0,
            padding:20,

      });

    });
  }
}
```

**banner-carousel.component.html**

```
  <div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: I have had similar problem. Try to move that init function from `ngOnInit()` to `ngAfterViewInit()`, it's another webhook which is better for that situation since now whole component could be loaded since your call

Comment: @ArturCzopek didn't work, same result.